Is there a function can modify map's value and return the iterator?
What I want is to insert a pair<key, value> into the map (create it if not existed, modify it otherwise), and got the value's pointer, to let others use.
here is a demo code:
#include <map>
using namespace std;
std::map<int, int> a = {{1, 1}};
int* set_and_return_value() {
  // option 1: a[1] = 2; return &(a[1]); i think it's ugly
  const auto [it, ok] = a.emplace(1, 2); 
  return &(it->second);
  // emplace is good, but it won't modify the existed key's value
}

So, is there a function, can return the iterator after real insert the pair?

Are you just looking for insert_or_assign?

Assigning via iterator does not invalidate the iterator, you can use that and the return value of emplace to conditionally assign if the insertion failed:
#include <map>

using namespace std;
std::map<int, int> a = {{1, 1}};
auto set_and_return_it() {
    const auto [it, inserted] = a.emplace(1, 2);
    if (!inserted) {
        it->second = 2;
    }
    return it;
}

If you want it more generic, use try_emplace to avoid constructing 2 twice.
template<typename K, typename T>
auto set_and_return_it(K&& key, T&& value) {
    const auto [it, inserted] = a.try_emplace(std::forward<K>(key), std::forward<T>(value));
    if (!inserted) {
        it->second = std::forward<T>(value);
    }
    return it;
}


Is there any reason to do this instead of .insert_or_assign() as suggested in comments?

Thanks Quimby, it's good, but as @G.M said, insert_or_assign seems already implement it

@HolyBlackCat No, I do not think so, I was just not aware it exists.

In your code you return a pointer to the mapped value, thats not an iterator (which would refer to both the key and the mapped value). If you not actually need an iterator, but merely a pointer/reference to the mapped value, then operator[] does that out of the box:
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::map<int,int> a;
    (a[1] = 2) = 3;       // (a[1] = 2) is a reference to the mapped value
    std::cout << a[1];
}

Output:
3

A more efficient way to do the same is via insert_or_assign (which actually does return a std::pair<iterator,bool>):
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::map<int,int> a;
    a.insert_or_assign(1,2).first->second = 3;
    std::cout << a[1];
}

Output:
3


This is worse than .insert_of_assign because it default-constructs the missing element just to overwrite it later.

@HolyBlackCat right, added the insert_or_assign code
